# Cannot resolve module 'babel-runtime/core-js/object/define-properties'

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to create a plugin for Vue application. I got an error when I wrote the following code:

```
export default function(Vue){
    Vue.auth = Authentication;

    Object.defineProperties(Vue.prototype, {
        $auth: {
            get() {return Vue.auth; }
        }
    });
}
```

and the error is:

> ERROR in ./src/authentication.js Module not found: Error: Cannot
>   resolve module 'babel-runtime/core-js/object/define-properties' in
>   D:\Dropbox\www\Vue\src  @ ./src/authentication.js 7:24-81

What's the problem here? I couldn't solve it. Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same error: install babel-runtime

```
npm install babel-runtime --save
```